# Angular dynamic column name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have filter function that I need to filter my array data based on receiving column name, my question is how do I place3 my receiving column name into my filter?

#### static code (sample)

```
this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
  item.name.indexOf(filterFormData.formInput) !== -1
);
```

`item.name` name is column of my array data therefore it will only search in `names`

#### my code

```
search(column): void {
      this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
        item.column.indexOf(filterFormData.formInput) !== -1
      );
}
```

`column` is the name that I get from search form it can be column `name` or column `id` or column `status` etc.

The thing is that I want use dynamic column name instead of hard coded `item.name` i.e. `item.status` / `item.id` / `item.name`

**any idea?**

Comment: what is the structure of `DataItem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access properties on your object by variable in the following way:

```
item[column]
```

where column is a keyof item, so this should work:

```
search(column): void {
      this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
        item[column]indexOf(filterFormData.formInput) !== -1
      );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, may i ask 1 more thing? how can I remove case sensitive from this filter? currently is case sensitive i don't want that

Comment: you can lower both strings to lowercase - someString.toLowerCase(), and then casing is no longer relevant and ignored

Comment: like this `filterFormData.formInput.toLowerCase()`?

Comment: yes, but you need to run it on both strings: item[column].toLowerCase().indexOf(filterFormData.formInput.toLowerCase())